# Composition in Scala, based on objects (singletons)

Tags: scala, object, composition

I want to make a composition with two objects. I can do it with objects nesting:

```
object Composition {
  object SomePartOfComposition {
    // some body
  }
}
```

But the body of SomePartOfComposition is such long, that I want it in a separate file. How can I do that?

// edit

I know, that I can use trait. But I want strict one to one relation - it is a singleton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
object Composition {
  object SomePartOfComposition extends SomePartTrait
}

trait SomePartTrait{
   //in it's own file
   //implement the body here
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work, but it is not relation one to one, every object can have this trait.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That's a feature, not a bug, as it enables reuse.   If you actually do need the gaurantee you describe, you'll need to use textual inclusion.

Comment: Defining all fields as public vars may be perceiving as future too - but it isn't;).

Comment: You'll need to clarify just _why_ you need such a restriction, if you wish to get a decent answer.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified why it matters that one object is nested in the other, so I assume that you just want the syntax to look like `A.B`.  So:

```
//File A
object A {
  val B = C
}

// File C
object C {
  import A._
  // All your code, written just like it was placed inside A
}
```

If this is not what you want, please edit the question to explain all the criteria.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a strict one to one relationship when using traits by defining the self type of the trait to be the type of the object:

```
object Composition {
  object SomePartOfComposition extends SomePartOfCompositionTrait
}

trait SomePartOfCompositionTrait {
  this: Composition.SomePartOfComposition.type =>
  // body
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's impressively degenerate.  I had no idea that was possible, and am absolutely certain that I will never do it.

Comment: @Dave Griffith: Yeah, it doesn't seem like one should do that, but it came to my mind when I read "I know, that I can use trait. But I want strict one to one relation".